# Send Email to CurrentItem:CreatedBy not working in workflow

Tags: designer-workflow

I have created two workflows which are supposed to send an email to the creator of a list item. The 'email user' clause seems identical in both cases but in the seconc case it doesn't seem to work. Any idea why? Here are screenshots of the two workflows:

Worfklow 1:
[image]

Workflow 2:
[image]

The only other possibly relevent detail to my mind is that the first workflow is set to start automatically when the list item is created whereas the second is set to start automatically when an item is changed.

For the second workflow, the second and third 'then' clauses work fine so I'm confident that the condition is being satisfied.

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: How's your outgoing email settings, and user profile sync doing?

Comment: Is it online or on-prem environment ?

Comment: @Mike I don't really know how to check those settings but I'm guessing that the outgoing email settings are working OK because the email in the first workflow works fine. Also, in the second workflow I cc myself in the email and I receive the email fine.

Not sure about user profile sync - what is that?

Comment: @MonicaJagani It's a University environment, and students submit forms to us either using a campus computer or they can access it remotely. The first workflow is to send a receipt to students when they submit a form, the second is triggered by ticking a checkbox our end to send an email to them to say that they are on our waiting list.

Comment: Weirdly, this just seemed to resolve itself and the very same workflows that were not working now are. Thanks for the comments :)

Comment: Weirdly, this just seemed to resolve itself and the very same workflows that were not working now are. Thanks for the comments :)